# How does Smule Sing Audio Effects work?

Tags: android, c++, ios, audio, audio-recording

There's a Karaoke App on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smule.singandroid) and [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smule-sing/id509993510) called Smule - Sing Karaoke. I used that app to sing many songs. But now being an Android Developer I really wonder how those audio effects actually work. Is there anything to do with Android/Java or they just write native C++ codes manipulate the audio. How much time or what expertise needed to do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

There are many DSP/audio processing libraries out there written both in Java or C++
such as [TarsosDSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) or [Tuna](https://github.com/Theodeus/tuna)

I cannot recommend any of them as this question might be off-topic, I suggest to google it. You will find many results

Comment: I'll try to use **TarsosDSP** to create a dummy app, let's see what happens. Thanks for telling me about this library.